# how can i add add a share icon on the toolbar in material design to perform the shaing action

Tags: android

i am using the material design in one of my works. I would like to add the features like search, share(to use like share intent) etc on the toolbar . I made search on Google but didn't get a correct answer. Can anyone help me please..
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [Adding an Easy Share Action](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html), it should help.

Comment: yess.. i completed it by the ShareActionProvider thank u..